# Object name/value array only returning 1 value, instead of 3

Tags: arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have created an array that I am struggling to access. Can you help with this newb problem.

```
var Obj = [Companies :
    {Company : "MPP",
    Details : {Address : "test@test.com",
              Phone : "something"},
    Company : "UKP1",
    Details : {Address : "test2@test.com",
               Phone : "somethingelse"},
    Company : "UKP2",
    Details : {Address : "test3@test.com",
               Phone : "something3else"}
    }
]

//result0:
Obj.Companies;
{Company: "UKP2", Details: {…}}

//result1;
Obj.Companies[1];
VM1393:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Can you tell me what I am missing to see this as an array.
I switched to object array as thought json array was messier, and had similar problems with that anyway.

I want to be able to use jquery.each() on the Obj.
ie. access the below in an array style.

- obj.Companies[i].Company;
- obj.Companies[i].Details.Address;
- obj.Companies[i].Details.Phone;

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it's not going to help future readers because it's a typo-like issue. @Craig just change your `Obj` to this: `var Obj = { Companies: [ { Company: 'MPP', ... }, ... ] }`

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek thanks, but I run into these typo like issues plenty - and also see plenty of answers on here that help me spot the typo.
As per my selected answer below, I have pointed out the difference that a future reader could hopefully now spot too.
Personally I find these types of questions really helpful if they fit my problem - there isn't enough of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some changes to your object model (converting from array to object)

```js
let Obj = {
  Companies: [{
      Company: "MPP",
      Details: {
        Address: "test@test.com",
        Phone: "something"
      }
    },
    {
      Company: "UKP1",
      Details: {
        Address: "test2@test.com",
        Phone: "somethingelse"
      }
    },
    {
      Company: "UKP2",
      Details: {
        Address: "test3@test.com",
        Phone: "something3else"
      }
    }
  ]
}

console.log(Obj.Companies[1].Company);
console.log(Obj.Companies[1].Details.Address);
console.log(Obj.Companies[1].Details.Phone);
```

Comment: Thanks Panos.
For future reference the main difference that I can see is that you wrapped curly brackets around each company, with the comma on the outside of the curly bracket - ie. after "details" sub array was 2 curlies and a comma
This worked for me, very helpful thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi first of all string values in JSON need to be enclosed in double inverted comas 
and your Companies contain list of companies please make it array of objects as i shown below,  it will work

```
{
"Companies": [{
            "Company": "MPP",
        "Details": {
            "Address": "test@test.com",
            "Phone": "something"
        }
    },
    {
        "Company": "UKP1",
        "Details": {
            "Address": "test2@test.com",
            "Phone": "somethingelse"
        }
    },
    {
        "Company": "UKP2",
        "Details": {
            "Address": "test3@test.com",
            "Phone": "something3else"
        }
    }
]
}
```